# Get website's name from where the link was redirected to my application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to make an application that records not only the hits on my website but also the names of the websites from where the client is redirected to mine via a link. Considering I know every link I am going to place external, I thought I can create an action method that takes a param for a get request so the link href could be like **mywebapp.com/index/CameFromLink1** and param differ for each link I know I will have. From there just increment a row in the database and I hide the param from url when the view is returned. But maybe there is a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use http referrer which let you learn where user came from. Also consider that it can be modifiable.